# Cannot mount partition - does not start on physical sector boundary?

Tags: linux, partition, disk

I have just moved a 3TB disk from an external USB enclosure to inside a computer and I cannot see the only one ext4 partition which is supposed to be there. The disk has extremely important data that I cannot lose. Please advise how to proceed, here are some details:

```
$ sudo mount -vvv -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/
mount: /mnt: /dev/sdb1 is not a valid block device.
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
GPT PMBR size mismatch (732566645 != 5860533167) will be corrected by w(rite).
Disk /dev/sdb: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           1 732566645 732566645 349.3G ee GPT

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

$ sudo parted /dev/sdb print
Error: /dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label
Model: ATA WDC WD30EZRX-00D (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

lshw output (excerpt):

```
 *-scsi:1
      physical id: 2
      logical name: scsi1
      capabilities: emulated
    *-disk
         description: ATA Disk
         product: WDC WD30EZRX-00D
         vendor: Western Digital
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sdb
         version: 0A80
         serial: WD-WCC1T1561951
         size: 2794GiB (3TB)
         capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
         configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
       *-volume UNCLAIMED
            description: EFI GPT partition
            physical id: 1
            bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,1
            capacity: 349GiB
            capabilities: primary nofs
```

Comment: Have you actually tried to mount the disk via `mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/point`? All of the physical disks in my `CentOS 7.5` file server give that message except for the one containing the OS and they always mount with no issues.

Comment: Yes, there is no such device as /dev/sdb1.

Comment: Add that command and the output to your question. In fact, use this command: `mount -vvv -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/point`.

Comment: I suggest you move the disk back into the enclosure and copy the data to a safe place. There is probably a mismatch between the logical sector size that the disk uses and what the enclosure emulates. Fdisk is confused, because it interprets the partition structure with the wrong sector size.

Comment: I would rather fix it, as I do not have free disk capacity to fully back up the drive.

Comment: @NasirRiley Added, however it is not very informative as there is no such device as /dev/sdb1.

Comment: Run `fsck.ext4` on the disk. If no errors turn up, return it to the external enclosure, backup the data, and then reinstall it to the computer, format it, and return the data. I'm hoping that you have a backup of it already.

Comment: Do **not** do anything that makes changes to the disk before putting it back into the enclosure. Do not let fsck "correct" anything.

Comment: To add to what Johan said, use `fsck.ext4 -n` or `e2fsck -n` which will send any errors to standard output instead of repairing them. If you run it without the -n switch, it will prompt but it's better just to run it with the `-n` switch.

Comment: In fact, don't run `fsck` at all.  This is another example of why comment answers should be taken with a large dose of salt.

Comment: `fdisk` has nothing to do with GPT partitions. Use `gdisk` instead.

Comment: @iporsircer For the record, fdisk has been able to handle GPT disks for a few years now.

Comment: If you have "extremely important data" on any single storage device and cannot afford to make a backup on another device, stop using the device right now and start collecting money until you have a real backup. Do not mess with the device (such as take it from USB enclosure) until you have a backup!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment answerers are not reading the output in your question.  The output tells us this:

- ```
  GPT PMBR size mismatch (732566645 != 5860533167) will be corrected by w(rite).
  ```

  `fdisk` is telling you that you have an EFI partition table with a so-called "protective" old-style MBR partition record.  But the protective partition record does not correctly protect the contents of your disc, because it ends way before the actual end of the disc, leaving a couple of TiB of free space unaccounted for.  `fdisk` says that it will fix this for you.  **Do not attempt to use `fdisk` to do so.**  `fdisk` is wrong.
- ```
  Disklabel type: dos
  Disk identifier: 0x00000000
   
  Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
  /dev/sdb1           1 732566645 732566645 349.3G ee GPT
  ```

  So `fdisk` has decided to not show you the EFI partition table at all.  It is showing you the "protective" old-style MBR partition table instead, as if *that* were how you had partitioned your disc.  That contains one entry, which is really (since it is type `ee`) a dummy entry that is supposed to encompass the entire disc, including the EFI partition table.  But it is only 732566645 sectors long, which is roughly 349GiB, not 2.7TiB.

  This is one of several reasons why it is wrong to run `fsck` against this.  **It is not a disc volume containing a formatted filesystem.**  It is a dummy old-style partition that is supposed to span the entire disc.
- ```
  Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
  ```

  This is a red herring.  Your dummy protective partition is *supposed* to begin at sector 1.  Sector 1 is where the EFI partition table begins.  It is the alignment of the *real* partitions, recorded in the new EFI partition table that `fdisk` isn't reading, that matters, and that for performance reasons.  You should be able to mount misaligned volumes.  But you haven't even got as far as using the right partition table, so whether this is even a problem in the first place is unknown.

  However, it is likely that it is not.  Alignment is likely *entirely* a red herring here.  Because what you are experiencing is well known, and is *something else*.
- ```
  $ sudo parted /dev/sdb print
  Error: /dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label
  ```

  `parted` is failing to read your EFI partition table, too.  Unlike `fdisk`, it isn't falling back to treating your disc as being partitioned in the old style, and reporting one big dummy partition.  It is failing outright.
- ```
  size: 2794GiB (3TB)
  …
  description: EFI GPT partition
  physical id: 1
  bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,1
  capacity: 349GiB
  ```

  `lshw` is seeing a 3TB (2.7TiB) disc.  It is *also* seeing the EFI partition table.  But your EFI partition table claims that this is a 349GiB disc.

Why did 2.7TiB become 349GiB?

Well, notice what you get when you multiply 349GiB by 8.

When it is in your USB disc enclosure, the system thinks that your disc has 4KiB sectors, and everything has been accessing it using that as the sector size.  In the USB enclosure, the rest of the system sees your disc with its native, *true*, sector size. 
 Moreover, with 4KiB sectors 732566645 sectors *really does* encompass the entire 2.7TiB of your disc, and both the old-style protective partition and the actual EFI partition table have the right numbers.

Outwith your USB disc enclosure, your disc is being read in "512e" compatibility mode, where most of the system pretends that your disc has 0.5KiB sectors.  (There is a more complex explanation to do with a second inverse transformation undoing the first when the USB enclosure is involved, but I am glossing over that here, as it is beyond the scope of this answer.)  The partition start and size numbers in your partition tables, and indeed anything else that points to a logical block address on your disc, are all wrong.

4KiB is 8 times 0.5KiB.

Downgrading from native 4KiB sector sizes to "512e" is possible, but it is not for the fainthearted.  I recommend as the far simpler course of action that you put the disc *back* into the enclosure to read it, where it will be seen with its true 4KiB sector size by the rest of the system and the numbers will come out right.

## Further reading

- https://superuser.com/questions/719844/
- https://superuser.com/questions/985305/
- https://superuser.com/questions/1271871/
- https://superuser.com/questions/852475/
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2011). *[The gen on disc partition alignment.](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/disc-partition-alignment.html)*
  .  Frequently Given Answers.
- https://superuser.com/questions/339288/
- https://superuser.com/questions/331446/

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense and is very informative. Can you please just explain if it is possible to downgrade the sector size without data loss and if yes, what is the required process for that?